# Alternate command for selenium.selectWindow("") in webdriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, selenium-rc

We are switching from Selenium RC to Webdriver, but most of the commands after converting in to Webdriver are not working .

The web driver statement for `selenium.selectwindow(" title")` is `driver.switchTo().window(v2);` is not working (`String v2=driver.getWindowHandle();`) and getting exception as

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Unable to locate frame: {c4fea83b-a784-4278-a490-762bdf80a7df}
```

Kindly suggest.

Thanks,

Comment: tried with (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
          driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); 
      } but its throwing exception "Unable to locate element".

Answer (score 1):

The `getWindowHandle()` function returns the current window, I think you cannot switch to the current window.

You want to use `getWindowHandles()` to find other windows.

For an example and similar issue see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112209/how-to-handle-the-new-window-in-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 1):

This is how I implemented a quick utility function to switch to a window based on the title:

```
public static void switchToWindowWithTitle(String title, WebDriver driver) {
    Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for(String handle : windowHandles){  
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);  
        if (driver.getTitle().contains(title)) {
          break;  
        }  
     }
}
```

This iterates over the window handles looking for the right one, and switches to it.